# Unknown type name 'ssize_t'

Tags: c

I am currently experiencing the error

> Unknown type name 'ssize_t'

I had a look at [Where is ssize_t defined in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190317/where-is-ssize-t-defined-in-linux)
but the error remained.

I added the

```
#include <sys/types.h>
```

My function is

```
ssize_t ss_size(sparse_set_ptr sparse_set)
{
    return false;
}
```

What could be the cause of the problem and can it be fixed?
Also I am running C Executable Language Standard: C99

Comment: The problem was fixed. Since I am using CLion and running it on Windows 10, what I had to do was switch to the MinGW toolchain. To access the MinGW toolchain -- go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains -> Drag MinGW to the top of the list. 

This is the solution that worked in my case.

Answer (score 3):

From `man ssize_t:

> ```
> ssize_t  
>     Include:  <sys/types.h>.   Alternatively, <aio.h>, <monetary.h>,
>     <mqueue.h>, <stdio.h>, <sys/msg.h>, <sys/socket.h>, <sys/uio.h>,
>     or <unistd.h>.
> ```

Try all these one by one, with one of them it should work.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Since I am using CLion and running it on Windows 10, all I had to do was switch to the MinGW toolchain.

Answer (score 3):

Note that even if you include `<sys/types.h>`, the type might not be defined if you specify a strict C standard with GCC (`-std=c99`) rather than the GNU variant (`-std=gnu99`). In fact, you don't need to explicitly include `<sys/types.h>` with POSIX 2008 (2018) or the prior version, POSIX 2004; it is effectively included automatically.

If you're including `<sys/types.h>` and still see the problem, then you need to enable the POSIX extensions, probably with `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` — the number's easier to remember than `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` which is a valid alternative.  Both these select POSIX 2008; there are other values for other versions of POSIX.  There are a few subtle differences between X/Open and POSIX (X/Open might till specify a few things that POSIX does not), but they're minimal and seldom relevant.  The `#define` must appear before any system header is included. It could be specified on the command line as `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide which standard you want to use: C99 or Posix.

If you want to use the type `ssize_t`, then you have to define (activate) that standard in your sources, see [man feature_test_macros](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).

But beware, if you activate any standard, which enables the desired Posix standard, you're not pure C99 anymore.